# TypeScript fails to infer type of an iterable

Tags: typescript

I got stuck trying to make TypeScript correctly infer an underlying iterable type, for function `spread` below, which is supposed to take an iterable of iterable types, infer type of the underlying iterable and return a new iterable with that underlying type.

```
interface Output<T, R> {
    (i: Iterable<T>): Iterable<R>;
}

function pipe<T, A>(i: Iterable<T>, p0: Output<T, A>): Iterable<A>;
function pipe(i: Iterable<any>, ...p: Output<any, any>[]): Iterable<any> {
    return []; // dummy iterable
}

// I'm trying to implement this function:
function spread<T extends Iterable<R>, R>(): Output<T, R> {
    return (iterable: Iterable<T>) => ({
        [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<R> {
             return null as any; // dummy, for now
        }
    });
}

pipe(['text'], spread());
// expected types: spread => Output<string, string>, pipe => Iterable<string>
// actual types: spread => Iterable<string, unknown>, pipe => Iterable<unknown>

pipe([[1, 2], [3, 4]], spread());
// expected types: spread => Output<number[], number>, pipe => Iterable<number>
// actual types: spread => Output<number[], unknown>, pipe => Iterable<unknown>
```

In my mind, function `spread` has the right template signature, but in the two examples above, the iterable type resolves into `unknown`, which I cannot understand why.

The underlying `spread`, in the meantime, infers into `<T, unknown>`, and so `pipe` fails to infer the type also.

---

This is for [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library that I'm working on. I have implemented numerous operators, without problems, but got stuck with the [`spread` type inference](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops/blob/main/src/ops/spread.ts).

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir), I was able to [properly finish the `spread` operator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops/blob/main/src/ops/spread.ts) :)

Comment: In your example, the generic type argument for `A` is never provided to `pipe`, so it's `unknown`. [TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAvdBW)

Comment: @jsejcksn The reason `pipe` doesn't receive the correct type is because `spread` infers into `spread<T, unknown>`. Function `pipe` simply reuses that second type. I'm trying to understand why `spread` infers incorrectly. I want type to be inferred automatically.

Comment: Let me know if it https://tsplay.dev/wX2Okm works for you. I don't think `pipe` is suitable for this case since you need to mutate your array.

Comment: @vitaly-t in `spread` can `T` and `R` be different ? If so how are they related ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir As per the `Output` declaration shown, `T` is for the input iterable, `R` is for the return iterable.

Comment: @captain-yossarian In the code you showed, version for the numbers, `pipe` result infers into `number[]` instead of `number`. I have updated the code above with comments, to explain the expectations better.

Comment: @vitaly-t how do you want to apply `p0` to first argument ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian `p0` consumes the input iterable, and outputs a new iterable. I'm not sure how to explain it better. So I have updated the question with the links to the entire library + this new `spread` operator that I'm working on. See the last addition at the bottom. Maybe that will shed some light :)

Comment: I have noticed that in each your operator you are using `iterable` argument from curried function whereas in your `spread` you dont

Comment: @captain-yossarian If I add any input of type `R` to the `spread` operator - `value: R`, then suddenly everything is inferred correctly. So that seems to be the issue, as you spotted correctly, well done! But now I need to figure out how to resolve this, because operator `spread` doesn't need any parameters.

Comment: @vitaly-t please provide an example with used `iterable`. I believe Titian Cernicova-Dragomir is very close to solution if already not resolved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly spread will transform  an `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` into and `Iterable<T>`.

This means that the function returned by spread should have the signature `(iterable: Iterable<Iterable<T>>) => Iterable<T>`. Using your types it should be `Output<Iterable<T>, T>`. So there is no need for the `R` argument as the input and output are related

```
interface Output<T, R> {
    (i: Iterable<T>): Iterable<R>;
}

function pipe<T, A>(i: Iterable<T>, p0: Output<T, A>): Iterable<A>;
function pipe(i: Iterable<any>, ...p: Output<any, any>[]): Iterable<any> {
    return []; // dummy iterable
}

function spread<T>(): Output<Iterable<T>, T> {
    return (iterable: Iterable<Iterable<T>>) => ({
        [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T> {
             return null as any; // dummy, for now
        }
    });
}

let r = pipe(['text'], spread()); // Iterable<string>

let r2 = pipe([[1, 2], [3, 4]], spread()); // Iterable<number>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=63&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIFcwAdMB4AqANMgEoB8yA3gFDJ3IAUwAXMgJKRRwBGANhATIBKVh2g9+ucgG5qAX2rUY6EAjDAA9iGRZgWAUWQBBMk1GcJBssSwAGVhmx5DJkewt8BJ2ctXqtOnoQZu7inrhwIACe1sgAdAlYDpg4YBHRxJExANoAum5iXOFZFDT0yFAQYOhQ2nnSyAD0jcgAJugAth1RyMAe-PKKvmqa2gDOWJVwrYIMbo6puIWWgsT4pbT0ldW1jH1h-OYHAsvh68LIALwUDGXl9NkAylEd3Bq8cftcYBpQuXNHb6-QRUTb3cHbGraEDoXi8ZBwMYI6INZptTrdYgwX7IEAaADuYPuCnKciEsgU1H4YAqV0C+gY2QA5JAAB5gJm5YgTKatObkpotU6SMZgKCgADmZEU1IqACY6boGdlsgBGYhyrnIbIAZmIABZclqeRBpvzUUL+gIYa9oGQgA)

Comment: Looks like this one does it! I'm gonna do some extensive type testing in other advanced cases, to see it is still good, and will accept the answer then. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, this solved it! Thank you so much! ;)

Comment: I was able to finish [the spread operator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops/blob/main/src/ops/spread.ts) :)

Comment: @vitaly-t Congrats :)